# Cannot install Keras on Pycharm on Macbook

Tags: python, pycharm, keras

Macbook.

I can perform "pip install Keras==1.0.8" successfully on terminal though.

**Problem: Installing Keras to Pycharm, cannot make it.**

Error as shown by screenshots below:
[image]

[image]

Comment: since `I can perform "pip install Keras==1.0.8" successfully on terminal though`, I think you can change the Python Env in PyCharm, because the keras is already in your Python libraray

Answer (score 1):

There are some non-python dependencies for Keras, so pip won't install them and fails if they are not found. The error here is related to fortran compiler and can be resolved by installing for example `gfortran`. But there would be probably other packages that you miss.

I recommend taking steps in [installation guide of theano on OS X](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/install.html#mac-os) because for now keras depends on theano. If you take the steps to have a working installation of theano there shouldn't be any problem installing Keras with pip.